# Calculating the "e" constant using Haskell's until function

Tags: haskell

I want to calculate the "e" constant using Haskell's (Prelude) built-in until function. I want to do something like this:

```
enumber = until (>2.7) iter (1 0)

iter x k = x + (1/(fact (k + 1)))

fact k = foldr (*) 1 [1..k]
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ a -> a
Expected type: (a -> a) -> a -> a
  Actual type: a -> a -> a
Relevant bindings include enumber :: a -> a (bound at Lab2.hs:65:1)
In the second argument of ‘until’, namely ‘iter’
In the expression: until (> 2.7) iter (1 0)
```

By "e" I mean e = 2.71828..

Comment: _e_ is usually called Euler's number. (Though it's arguable whether it really deserves a name of its own, seeing that basically its _only_ use is as the base of the natural exponential function, and that is written `exp` anyway. It doesn't really make any sense to calculate _e_ itself, instead of `exp` directly.) — Regarding your compilation errors: please _always add type signatures_, they tend to make such errors far less incomprehensible.

Comment: `(1 0)` is surely not what you want. `f x y` means `(f x) y`, not `f (x y)`.

Comment: A more common name for `foldr (*) 1` is `product`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concrete mistake that causes this error is the notation `(1 0)`. This doesn't make any sense in Haskell, it is parsed such that `1` is a function which is applied to `0`, and the result then used. You apparently mean to pass both 1 and 0 as (initial) arguments. That's what we have *tuples* for, written `(1,0)`.

Now, before trying to make anything definitions, we should make clear what *types* we need and write them out. Always start with your type signatures, they guide you a lot to you the actual definitions should look!

```
enumber :: Double -- could also be a polymorphic number type, but let's keep it simple.

type Index = Double -- this should, perhaps, actually be an integer, but again for simlicity use only `Double`

fact :: Index -> Double
```

now, if you want to do something like `enumber = until (>2.7) iter (1,0)`, then `iter` would need to both add up the series expansion, and increment the `k` index (`until` knows nothing about indices), i.e. something like

```
iter :: (Double, Index) -> (Double, Index)
```

But right now your `iter` has a signature more like

```
iter :: Double -> Index -> Double
```

i.e. it does not do the index-incrementing. Also, it's curried, i.e. doesn't accept the arguments as a tuple.

Let's try to work with a tuple signature:

```
iter :: (Double, Index) -> (Double, Index)
iter (x,k) = ( x + 1/(fact (k + 1)), k+1 )
```

If you want to use this with `until`, you have the problem that you're always working with tuples, not just with the accumulated results. You need to throw away the index, both in the termination condition and in the final result: this can easily be done with the `fst` function

```
enumber = fst $ until ((>2.7) . fst) iter (1,0)
```

Now, while this version of the code will type-check, it's neither elegant nor efficient nor accurate (being greater than 2.7 is hardly a meaningful condition here...). As chi remarks, a good way of summing up stuff is the `scanl` function.

Apart from avoiding to manually increment and pass around an index, you should also avoid calculating the entire factorial over and over again. Doing that is a pretty general code smell (there's a reason `fact` isn't defined in the standard libraries)

```
recipFacts :: [Double] -- Infinite list of reciprocal factorials, starting from 1/0!
recipFacts = go 1
 where go k = 1 : map (/k) (go (k+1))
```

Incidentally, this can also be written as a scan: `scanl (/) 1 [1..]` (courtesy of Will Ness).

Next we can use `scanl` to calculate the partial sums, and use some termination condition. However, because the series converges so quickly, there's actually a hack that works fine and is even simpler:

```
enumber :: Double
enumber = sum $ takeWhile (>0) recipFacts
           -- result: 2.7182818284590455
```

Here I've used the fact that the fast-growing factorial quickly causes the floating-point reciprocals to underflow to zero.

Of course, *really* there's not a need to sum anything up yourself at all here: the most to-the-point definition is

```
enumber = exp 1
```

and nothing else.

Comment: scanl is also useful for efficiently generating the list of all factorials by defining `factorials = scanl (*) 1 [1..]`. With this at hand, `recipFacts` is just `map (1/) factorials`.

Comment: Thanks for your precise explanation! I liked the method with the tuples, so I used it like this:`type Index = Double

iter :: (Double, Index) -> (Double, Index)
iter (x,k) = ( x + 1/(fact (k + 1)), k+1 )

enumber = fst$until ((>10) . snd) iter (1,0)`

Here, by checking the index, I can get the desired result.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe `scanl (/) 1 [1..]` is better, because it is incremental (avoids recalculations of products).

Comment: `takeWhile (>1e-16)` stops after producing 20 numbers instead of 179 for (>0) --  with the same result.

Comment: @WillNess: right, but I don't like hard-coding finite precision limits. I'd rather use a scan summation then, and choose the first element that's equal to the one before it.

Comment: *"the first that's equal to the one before it"* that's the same as using `(>0)` isn't it? The problem with it is, if we were to switch to an exact number type, like ratios, it'd never stop. I don't see a way around using *some* tolerance value there.

Comment: @WillNess: “same as using `(>0)`” – conceptually right of course, but no. A decreasing sequence of floating-point numbers has much more accuracy than its accumulated series can make use of. As you've noticed yourself, those elements below 10⁻¹⁶ simply _won't contribute at all_ to the sum, though they are themselves `/=0`. — Switching to a type like `Ratio` doesn't make any sense, because _e_ ∉ ℚ.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you're of course entirely correct, thanks for the clarifications! :) --- switching to ratios may be justified if you want to have control over a precision of representation (have 10^-100, say). Speaking *hypothetically* of course, as pertaining the *e*, but there *are* converging series whose initial members grow enormously large, at first, like e.g. Fresnel integral.

Answer (score 2):

```
enumber = until (>2.7) iter (1 0)
                  --        ^^^^^
```

Above you are applying "function" `1` to argument `0`. This can't work.

You may want to use a pair instead `(1, 0)`. In that case, not that `iter` must be changed to accept and return a pair. Also, the predicate `>2.7` must be adapted to pairs.

If you don't want to use pairs, you need a different approach. Look up the `scanl` function, which you can use to compute partial sums. Then, you can use `dropWhile` to discard partial sums until some good-enough predicate is satisfied.

---

An example: the first ten partial sums of `n^2`.

```
> take 10 $ scanl (+) 0 [ n^2 | n<-[1..] ]
[0,1,5,14,30,55,91,140,204,285]
```

Note that this approach works only if you compute all the list elements independently. If you want to reuse some computed value from one element to another, you need something else. E.g.

```
> take 10 $ snd $ mapAccumL (\(s,p) x -> ((s+p,p*2),s+p)) (0,1) [1..]
[1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255,511,1023]
```

Dissected:

```
mapAccumL (\(s,p) x -> ((s+p,p*2),s+p)) (0,1) [1..]
                         a   b    c      d e

s previous sum
p previous power of two
x current element of [1..]
a next sum
b next power of two
c element in the generated list
d first sum
e first power of two
```

Still, I am not a big fan of `mapAccumL`. Using `iterate` and pairs looks nicer.

Comment: Or, you could just pass `uncurry iter` instead of `iter` to `until`, and keep using the pairs...

Comment: Can you please give me an example (related to my problem, if possible), using the `scanl` function?